# Finding Django template inheritance chain?

Tags: django

Given the path to a Django template, is there any easy way to find a list of the template's inheritance chain? For example, if `mytemplate.html` inherited from `user-section-base.html`, which inherited from `global-base.html`, it would be something like:

```
>>> print(get_template_chain('myapp/mytemplate.html'))
>>> ['/project/myapp/templates/myapp/mytemplate.html', '/project/myapp/templates/myapp/user-section-base.html', '/project/myapp/templates/myapp/global-base.html']
```

I'm trying to write a static site generator that automatically regenerates static pages from Django templates, and I need to detect when the underlying template changes since last generation. For a single flat template with no inheritance, this is trivial, but for a template that inherits from a parent, which also inherits from a parent, I need to track changes of those files as well.

However, I can't find any simple way to retrieve this, short of manually parsing the `{% extends ... %}` tags directly. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can include html comments in your html files `<!-- file myapp/template block foo -->` and then "view page source" will tell you what you need. The only problem is keeping the comments correct, when files are cloned and edited to create other files. You might write a simple script to look for, say, `<!-- =file=` and check/update the filename that follows to reflect reality.

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way is to hook to the template rendering engine, and try doing it there. That however, will require a deep dive into its code. Unless you are already familiar with the code base, I would say that going for parsing is the easiest and fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hacky way ;-)  ...but if you are open to changing Django code, you can go to django/template/loader_tags.py and change the `ExtendsNode.render` return statement from

```
return compiled_parent._render(context)
```

to

```
return compiled_parent._render(context) + f'\n<!-- {compiled_parent.origin} -->'
```

and the rendered template will end with the full path of all your template-extends, e.g. for the file I'm working on right now:

```
</body>
</html>

<!-- c:\srv\lib\admindash\admindash\templates\admindash\html5.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\lib\admindash\admindash\templates\admindash\bootstrap3.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\lib\admindash\admindash\templates\admindash\site-admin.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\www\school\templates\site-admin.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\www\school\templates\page-admin.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\lib\dashboard\dashboard\templates\dashboard\tctr\home.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\lib\studentdb\studentdb\templates\studentdb\tctr\tctr-base.html -->
<!-- c:\srv\lib\studentdb\studentdb\templates\studentdb\tctr\candidates\candidate-base.html -->
```

Hooking into the template engine would be nice, but I'm not sure it can work out-of-the-box since `.render(..)` returns a string and thus loses all meta-data. Perhaps if you create your own `{% extends ... %}` tag..?